# Is article type "Perspectives" considered a scholarly paper?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

**Description:** "Perspectives have the same basic structure and length as review articles, however, they should be more speculative and very forward looking, even visionary. They offer the author the opportunity to present criticism or address controversy. Authors of perspectives are encouraged to be highly opinionated."

"Discover Environment publishes a wide range of article types, including but not limited to Research, Reviews, **Perspectives**, Comments, Brief Communications, Case Studies, Registered Reports, and Data Notes."

Comment: If you are asking whether your depertment (char, dean, promotion committee) will consider this a scholarly paper, I think it is best to ask them in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, they are scholarly, but probably not on the same scale as research reports. I think many professional societies publish at least one series, such as Communications of the ACM, that contain such a variety of reports.

How much it "counts" toward things like promotion, however, is an individual judgement and, especially for an early career, academic, they probably count fairly low.

Senior academics with a long history of publishing research that expands the knowledge in a field have more natural credibility in such things.

So, yes, scholarly, but not a replacement for more fundamental things. Not all papers are created equal.

Comment: "Sure, they are scholarly" - Some journals mentioned that for "Perspectives" papers peer-review is optional, at the discretion of the editor.

Comment: "Perspectives will be typically reviewed by a member of the editorial board who may ask the help of and an additional reviewer if needed, so the publication is expected to be fast." https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10827-021-00781-w